# Relative Clause after a Verb?

Tags: sentence

> It is indeed very striking how similar ideas are ***on which the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics based*** their main thoughts.

I have completely no idea on the structure of the above sentence. Can anyone please explain and tell me the name of the sort in grammar? I first thought the "on which ..." part was a relative clause modifying "idea", but I get puzzled by "their main thoughts". Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let's know how you (may have tried to) parse the sentence. And where you got into difficulty, to help us help you. (FYI, I could parse it and make sense of it without any issues.)

Comment: How similar ideas / on which the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics based their main thoughts / are. I parsed it this way.

Comment: (It is indeed very striking) (how similar) (ideas are) (on which) (the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics) (based their main thoughts). Take *how similar* as a phrase, not *similar ideas*. HTH.

Comment: so, (on which...their main idea) is relative pronoun clause right? it's actually, "the founders of modern theory ... main thoughts [on the ideas = on which]"?

Comment: @QnQ I think there's probably a typo there. The original presumably reads: *It is indeed very striking how similar **the** ideas are ...*

Comment: @Araucaria The definite article is not essential there. Even if so, its absence couldn't be a typo.

Comment: @Kris It's absence "couldn't be a typo" <---- How come?

Comment: @Araucaria https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How similar ideas on which the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics based their main thoughts are] is indeed very striking.

```
    | The bracketed NP subject of "is" is extraposed to the
    |  end of its clause and replaced by "it", giving:
```

It is indeed very striking how similar ideas [on which the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics based their main thoughts] are.

```
   | The bracketed relative clause modifier of "ideas"
   |  is extraposed to the end of its clause, giving:
```

It is indeed very striking how similar ideas are on which the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics based their main thoughts.

(These changes are not necessarily made in the above order.)

Comment: Can I change "on which" to "where" in the sentence above?

Comment: No.  "base" goes with "on".

Answer (score 0):

What a sentence. You're right that it's a relative clause modifying "ideas". Their ideas are the one object of the verb "based", "their main thoughts" are the other, and "the founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology and economics" is a noun phrase designating the subject.

Or, stating it another way:

The founders of modern theory in evolutionary biology, and in economics, based their main thoughts on strikingly similar ideas.

Comment: I would enjoy hearing your thoughts on how _ideas_ is an indirect object.

Comment: @KarlG - by valence "based" operates on two object arguments, semantically it's the same as "they based their main thoughts on (strikingly similar) ideas" and I compare it to "I put the book on the shelf" - you could call it a prepositional object, for the purpose of understanding a sentence I don't bother with the distinction.

Comment: I'm not sure how one would analyze the nominal versus the prepositional object of a bitransitive PP construction, but I seriously doubt it's "indirect object."

Comment: @KarlG - fair enough, I've removed the refences to direct and indirect objects.